# Can I use a human grade bug repellent for my dog?

Tags: dogs, safety, parasites, pest-control

I have a Xoloitzcuintle ([Mexican hairless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xoloitzcuintle)) and this time of the year in my part of the world, bugs really start to attack him.

As far as I know there are no commercial bug repellents for dogs, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in doubt, ask your vet. You should *"never ever** use anything made for humans without prior consultation simply because dogs might react differently and because they've got a far smaller body size.

It's certainly possible that repellents or toxins are indeed harmful to humans and dogs, but the dose would be too small to matter in the human case (think of drinking alcohol adults compared to children).

And not to forget there are options for dogs in the form of collars, sprays, food additions, etc.

There might be simple solutions, but we don't know the insects you'd like to avoid. For example, cold pressed coconut oil can be rubbed into the fur or added to the food and will repel ticks and mosquitoes to a certain degree. This even works for humans, too.

Comment: Thank you Mario. Indeed I asked my vet and he said "it shouldn't be a problem" although he also recommended the collar. I tend to stay away from tick repellents as he does not get ticks (only mosquitoes and such bother him) and I don't like to put more chemicals into his body than those strictly necessary.

Comment: @Gabriel Mosquitoes? Then definitely try the coconut oil. You can get a glass food grade for about 10-15 bucks (1 liter). Just make sure it's cold pressed. Melt a teaspoon full between your hands and rub it into the fur. Doesn't have to get all oily, the scent alone is enough. Rub excess oil into your arms or legs for extra protection for yourself, too.

Comment: Also, the coconut oil won't help forever; a few hours. If you can smell it, the pests can so, too.